# Should *-rec tags be added?

Tags: discussion, tags

A convention has been established on SuperUser.com where questions that ask for software recommendations, are tagged `software-rec`. I'm wondering if the same convention should be used here with `webapp-rec` and `bookmarklet-rec`.

I added the tag to a few questions, I just wanted to make sure people are okay with this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They can be, but I'm not crazy about the category.

It's not far off from shopping recommendations such as "what computer should I buy?" which is explicitly disallowed on Super User.

Comment: If they are all tagged consistently you can add them to your ignore list.

Comment: i find this category a bit useless as well, you can tag almost every question *-rec

Comment: @akira: it's only used for questions that are looking for a product/service that does something. If it really was for every question, Jeff probably wouldn't want this site in the first place, because it would basically be a glorified shopping recommendation site. Currently they are about 10% of questions.

Answer (score 12):

Readability is very poor. "rec" what the heck does that mean? "recreation", "reception". Perhaps a **separate** tag called "recommendation". Then you could tag like this if you wanted to:

```
[webapp] [recommendation]
```

Comment: I definitely agree.  I had no idea what it meant - from context, I was guessing misspelled *recquest* or something!

Comment: I agree that a more intuitive tag name should be used, I just followed the convention that was established on superuser.com to stay consistent. The reason `[webapp-recommendation]` isn't used is that it is [too long](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5935/superuser-tagging-question-software-hardware-product-recommendations#comment-18004).

Comment: Why would you need to specify "webapp" on a webapp site?

Comment: @Joe: You caught me. Really, it was only an example. Perhaps instead of "[webapp]" I should have used "[some-category]".

Comment: I support this instead of the ugly `webapp-rec` which I had no idea what it meant until I came to meta to ask the question.

Comment: 100% agree. I kept seeing it pop up & had to search meta (& found this question) to find out what `[webapp-rec]` even meant... Don't see any value in using `[*-rec]` over a simple `[recommendation]` tag.

Comment: Agreed.  I just had @Senseful add this tag to one of my questions and I had no idea what it meant, so I had to come here to find this question to understand it.

Comment: Definitely - `[webapp-rec]` is a crap tag, and is also the [most popular tag](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/tags) - I looked at the tags page and was quite confused by the top tag for a bit.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think `[webapp-rec]` is the best way to tag these questions.  Is using "rec" in the tag going to result in the best search results for users trying to search and find questions/answers?

Everything on this site should be a webapp, so I don't see the value of having "webapp" in the tag or a separate [webapp] tag.  I would favor using '[recommendation]' over '[rec]' for readability purposes.

Answer (score 3):

No.

This site no longer accepts questions asking for recommendations. Therefore, we shouldn't have tags promoting such. Ideally we'd get rid of [webapp-rec](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/webapp-rec), but there are too many questions and it would destroy too much good information. The guidance for that tag already says that such questions are off-topic.