# Is the [web-apps] tag partially redundant?

Tags: discussion, tags

**See also**: [Do we really need online in tags on a Web Applications site](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81/do-we-really-need-online-in-tags-on-a-web-applications-site)

---

Okay, on my general tag browsing tonight I've noticed a few questions which are being tagged with [[web-apps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-apps)].

While there are a number of questions which I could argue don't belong here ([this](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2050/what-is-your-most-used-web-application), [this](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/4007/how-to-improve-performance-and-speed-of-web-apps) and [this](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/3817/webapps-bandwidth-usage), for example) there are also a number of good questions about a specific application which have (usually) relevant tags to the question but are also tagged with [web-apps].

Examples (I'm linking to the revisions in the cases where I have retagged):

- [How can I view imdb top lists sorted by demographics to give more personalized ratings?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/4164/revisions)
- [Buyers remorse... Can I return "Groupons" I bought?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/4420/revisions)
- [Is there a way to change the appearance of Facebook?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/4425/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-appearance-of-facebook)

As paraphrased from the other question, surely the fact that the questions relate to web apps is implied by the fact they are being asked on a web application QA site.

While this is only by a couple of users and three example questions I wanted to get a community response so I know whether I can feel just in my brutal extermination of those poor tags.

Comment: There are a couple other tags that could be redundant or inconsistent:  web-apps, webapp-rec, and identify-this-app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed some of them so currently there are only 5 questions tagged with the web-apps tag (closed questions that need delete votes from high rep members and https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2050/what-is-your-most-used-web-application 44 votes 1000 views)

@tobeannounced seems to use the web-apps tag alot so I am not sure if he would want to pitch in his reasoning.

@eagle was the person I followed for the webapp-rec see

["Should Rec Tags be Added"](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54/should-rec-tags-be-added)

which is currently being used to tag questions that are asking for a list of X. Based on how meta discussion go, I would only assume that these questions either end up being ignored or deleted all together see

["Lets make a list of X questions"](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73/what-are-some-sites-or-lets-make-a-list-of-x-type-questions)

and on meta.stackoverflow

["Should we have a “List of X” close reason?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57226/should-we-have-a-list-of-x-close-reason)

The [identify this app](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/479/what-does-tag-x-mean-when-is-it-used/481#481) tag, I am not sure about, I like the idea but I definitely see this bringing about duplicate questions.