# Can we black list [web-application]?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

[web-application](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-application) has quite a number of questions tagged to it, but considering the name of this site seems to be rather redundant. I mean, technically, every question on here should have that tag.

There's no description of the tag, and I don't see anything about any of the questions that create a logical grouping.

I think the tag should be black-listed. As well as [web-applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-applications) and [web-apps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-apps).

See also: [Is the [web-apps] tag partially redundant?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/501/is-the-web-apps-tag-partially-redundant)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have removed the following tags from any questions on Web Application and they have been subsequently blacklisted.

- [web-application](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-application)
- [web-applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-applications)
- [webapp](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/webapp)
- [webapps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/webapps)
- [web-app](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-app)
- [web-apps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-apps)

Thanks go to [Rebecca](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/416/rebecca-chernoff) for sorting out the blacklisting.

Answer (score 11):

I agree that the [web-application](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-application) tag does not add any value to questions as every question should be about a web application. It is a meta tag for this site and should be removed.

As discussed in [the Death of Meta Tags](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/)

1. The [web-application](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-application) tag cannot work on its own as a tag to a question
2. The [web-application](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-application) tag can used to mean to some that they are looking for a web application (which is meta for this site) and others because of migrations from other SE sites.

Hopefully the other mods agree and a dev happily burns it.

Comment: I agree. Both `web-applications` and `web-apps` are pretty useless for WebApps. I say we click the button called BURNINATE!!

Answer (score -1):

there should be one tag as a catch-all for web apps that  don't have their own tag yet, & this tag should be **prominently** displayed to users on the submission page.  Ideally it would be recommended when a user attempts to submit a question without supplying any tags.   What happens when you BURNINATE a tag? does it delete all the questions which are tagged with that tag?

EDIT: Oops I just realized this post is almost 10 years old. ignore me