# Clean up and then blacklist the [application] tag

Tags: feature-request, tags, blacklist

I've just see that we have a tag called [application](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/application).

This seems to me to be redundant.

I'm guessing that it came about because people entered "email application" or some such into the tags.

<strike>Once</strike> Now this tag has been cleaned up <strike>we</strike> can we get it added to the blacklist?

NOTE: [We already blacklist `web-application` and its variants](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/841/can-we-black-list-web-application)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The tag list has been cleared.

[application](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/application) should show 0 posts currently.

Comment: You sir are a hero. I'll convert this into a feature request.

Comment: Cool, no problem